# Issues uploading file to Microsoft Form Recognizer

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I'm having some trouble while trying to send a PDF file to Microsoft's Form Recognizer service.

Instead of sending the PDF Url location, I need to send the PDF file. On my experience, sending files could be done using base64 but it seems that Microsoft service is not compatible with base64 format. Whenever I try sending the file the server responses:

> {
> "error": {
> "code": "1000",
> "message": "Invalid input file."
> }
> }

I need to know how I should convert my PDF to the required application/pdf "Binary PDF data". I can't find any documentation referring to this conversion.

The Form Recognizer API webpage is: https://brazilsouth.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-1-preview-3/operations/AnalyzeWithCustomForm

And here you can find the complete documentation webpage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/client-library?tabs=preview%2Cv2-1&pivots=programming-language-rest-api

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that base64-encoded requests are not supported.

If you are using curl and you want to send a local file, run this:

```sh
curl -i https://{endpoint}/formrecognizer/v2.1-preview.3/custom/models/{modelId}/analyze -H 'Content-Type: application/pdf' \
  -H 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {subscription key}' --data-binary @/path/to/your/file.pdf
```

The key parts are the `Content-Type` header, which must match a supported value, and the `--data-binary` flag, which is the path to a local PDF file. Be sure to include the `-i` flag so that you can see the `Operation-Location` header in the response, which is where you can retrieve the analyze results.

You may also want to take a look at the Form Recognizer SDKs for [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/client-library?tabs=preview%2Cv2-1&pivots=programming-language-csharp), [Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/client-library?tabs=preview%2Cv2-1&pivots=programming-language-java), [JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/client-library?tabs=preview%2Cv2-1&pivots=programming-language-javascript), and [Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/client-library?tabs=preview%2Cv2-1&pivots=programming-language-python).