# Form Recognizer custom model fails with invalid file type `{"error":{"code":"1000","message":"Invalid input file."}}`

Tags: python, python-requests, azure-form-recognizer

I have successfully trained a custom model for key value extraction, however any file or file type I use to evaluate the model is failing to return a result. So far I have tried both pdf and png files.

I have matched the query provided in [the API docs](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-1/operations/AnalyzeWithCustomForm) to create my query but it still fails, any suggestions?

```py
import requests
import json
import os
import pathlib

# path of file to evaluate
floc = 'path/to/file'

# extract file type
file_type = pathlib.Path(floc).suffix[1:]

# set headers with file type and our api key
headers = {
    'Content-Type': f'application/{file_type}',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': os.environ["AZURE_FORM_RECOGNIZER_KEY"]
}

# read in the file as binary to send
files = {'file': open(floc, 'rb')}

# post the file to be analysed
r = requests.post(
    f'https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/formrecognizer/v2.1/custom/models/{os.environ["MODEL_ID"]}/analyze',
    headers=headers,
    files=files
)

r
```

The result is `400` with the following error:

`{"error":{"code":"1000","message":"Invalid input file."}}`

A very similar query using the `layout/analyze` request works perfectly. I have also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66881466/issues-uploading-file-to-microsoft-form-recognizer) that has the same error but from cURL but it has not helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem but will leave my answer for any one else.

There were two main problems:

- sending the pdf with `files` rather than `data`
- using the default endpoint (https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com) rather than my own endpoint

The fix is found below:

```py
import requests
import json
import os
import pathlib

# path of file to evaluate
floc = 'path/to/file'

# extract file type
file_type = pathlib.Path(floc).suffix[1:]

# set headers with file type and our api key
headers = {
    'Content-Type': f'application/{file_type}',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': os.environ["AZURE_FORM_RECOGNIZER_KEY"]
}

# post the file to be analysed
r = requests.post(
    f'{endpoint}/formrecognizer/v2.1/custom/models/{os.environ["MODEL_ID"]}/analyze',
    headers=headers, 
    data=open(floc, 'rb') # send binary of your file
)

r
```

You can find your own `endpoint` value by going on to the Azure instance for your form_recognizer:

[image: Form recognizer instance info]